# In PhoneGap App, AJAX call error event gets triggered even the server returns 200 OK status

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, spring-security, cross-domain

I am using the below Ajax call to connect with Spring security from crossdomain (PhoneGap). The response I got is 200 OK - it has the expected response in JSON format. But the error event is getting fired due to CORS. On the Spring side, I have added a CORS filter to allow any type of URL (Access-Control-Allow-Origin = ' * ').

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: CONTEXTPATH + '/j_spring_security_check',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'text json',
    cache: false,
    crossdomain: false,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest',
    },
    success: function(data) {
    },
    error: function(data) {
    }
});
```

The response in the browser console is:

> POST XHR http://192.168.0.20:8080/startupbay/j_spring_security_check [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 260ms] Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.0.20:8080/startupbay/j_spring_security_check. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

The request and response headers are:

RESPONSE HEADER:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, x-requested-with, Origin, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:86400
Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-requested-with
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:0
Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2017 06:14:39 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

REQUEST HEADER:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.0.20:8080
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
origin:http://192.168.0.20:3000
```

In the Error section, I looked for the error mentioned in 'xhr'. The statusText:error, responseText:'', status:0.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

When I set the crossdomain:true, that time in the browser console I can see only the OPTIONS request, but not followed by the POST request.

Just to add, this issue is appearing only for the '/j_spring_security_check' URL. For another URL, the same type setup is working fine.

Comment: why are you setting `crossdomain: false` when it's clearly a cross domain request? though, that wont have any effect, since `crossdomain !== crossDomain`

Comment: `I can see only the OPTIONS request` - yes, and if the preflight (that's what the OPTIONS request is) fails, there will be no POST

Comment: Does the server process and respond to OPTIONS requests with the *appropriate CORS headers*?

Comment: The OPTIONS request status is 200 OK. But still there is no POST request sent. On server side, I am setting the CORS headers using the Spring filter. In debug mode I can see the headers are getting set correctly.

Comment: and the required OPTIONS response headers for CORS are all present and accounted for?

Comment: _and the required OPTIONS response headers for CORS are all present and accounted for?_   which one you are talking about? If you see the response header I added in this question. The first six headers are set by CORS server-side filter

Comment: the appropriate CORS headers that should be returned when a browser performs a preflight OPTIONS request